# CakePHP 3 Authentication on Production

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I have followed pretty much the tutorial from [the CakePHP website](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html) to add authentication to my website (except that I do not need any roles on my website, but just an admin login). On my machine the whole authentication works and also which pages I can access only as admin. I have copied the folder and the database to my web hoster, but there I have problems logging in.

This is what my code looks like:

in **config/routes.php** I have:

```
Router::prefix('admin', function($routes) {
  $routes->connect('/', ['controller'=>'Users','action'=>'login']);
  $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
});
```

in **src/Controller/Admin/UsersController.php**

```
 namespace App\Controller\Admin;
 use App\Controller\AppController;
 use Cake\Event\Event;

 class UsersController extends AppController {

  public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->Auth->allow(['logout']);
  }

  public function login(){
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Please check your username and password.'));
    }
  }
}
```

The entity **User** contains a method to do the hashing:

```
protected function _setPassword($password)
{
    return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
}
```

Finally, in **Controller/AppController.php** I have implemented the following, that should allow every logged-in user to access all pages.

```
class AppController extends Controller
{

    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'loginRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'requests',
                'action' => 'index'
            ],
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                'prefix' => false,
                'controller' => '/'
            ]
        ]);

    }

    public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
        if($this->request->session()->check('Auth.User.id')) {
           $this->layout = 'admin';
        } 
    }

    public function isAuthorized($user) 
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

As I said, this works on my local machine. However, on the server, I always get the following error:

> You are not authorized to access that location.

I tried various PHP versions, to make sure the error is not there. Using printouts, I could see that I pass the `if($user)` check in the `login()` method. However, now I really don't know how to proceed and I'm pretty clueless about possibly solutions. I have installed CakePHP in a subdomain on the webhoster - could that be a problem?

Comment: Could the problem be that I have just a subdomain of the hoster at the moment, not yet the full domain? Would I have to switch something in the app-config?

Comment: If you pass the identiy check, then the problem might be session related, like for example the cookie not being set (properly) or similar.

Comment: Check and ensure the session cookie path is same on your login page and the page you are trying to access.

Comment: How can I check/set this?

Comment: I just noticed that I get this warning on the page `Warning: The use statement with non-compound name 'PDO' has no effect in [/***/plugins/DebugKit/config/bootstrap.php, line 20]`. I found that a fix is to write `use \PDO` rather than `use PDO`, but that is what is written on line 20. Could that be somehow connected to the problem I have?

Comment: You seem to be using an outdated DebugKit version, that problem was [**fixed**](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit/commit/a16e5a564dcc0c3d737dd6e435411d7cfde50095) ([**2**](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit/commit/67979b075852d7d701ba402b2883c20240b99487)) when the plugin was in beta stage. Before trying to fix other problems, you should make sure that your app and its dependencies are up to date.

Comment: No, sorry, my comment was not clear enough: the file says `use \PDO` and is therefore the current version, but the error is still there. I am using the most up to date version of CakePHP.

Comment: It's not the current version if it has that line, the current version doesn't have it at all, it's not present anymore since version 3.0.0, the current version is 3.1.5. ps, please use @username tags in your responses, otherwise it isn't guaranteed that the one you are "talking" to gets notified.

Comment: @ndm hm, thanks for the hint on the version; I updated now using composer to 3.0.7 (3.1.5 is in beta as it seems), but still this does not solve the problem. after the login I get either redirected to `/` instead of being redirected to the page I set to redirect after login, or I get a `You are not authorized to access that location.`. How could I debug? Btw, would it help if I added the URL (of the subdomain) somewhere in `app.php`?

Comment: 3.1.5 is the current DebugKit version, 3.0.7 is the current CakePHP version. Anways, as already mentioned, this might be session related, so start by debugging the received and possibly sent cookies using your browsers network console.

Comment: That was a very good hint!  Checking the cookies, I could see the following: my web hoster somehow has built in a redirection to the domain (that is not yet activated). CakePHP as a result creates two cookies, one for the true URL, where a value for the key `CAKEPHP` is stored. The values for the keys `__utma` are stored for the domain to come. I tried to change the value of `fullBaseUrl`, but there my web hoster breaks when redirecting after login, as it tries to redirect to my domain...

Comment: I experimented a bit around: first, I had to set `fullBaseUrl`, then I found out that removing `return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());` will of course result in the login page still being displayed after login, but the login actually happening (and not being stopped by the redirect that comes from the webhoster because of the preview domain)